# Redirecionar para URL com valor de input preenchido

Tags: url, input, redirecionamento, value

Gostaria de saber se é possivel montar um redireciomento para uma tela de login de terceiro com o "value" do input preenchido?

seria apontar algo tipo:
`http://dominio.com.br/login?pt01=admin-51`

o input está assim:

```
<input id="P101-USERNAME" name="pt01" value="" placeholder="Usuário" type="text">
```

É possivel montar uma url que preencha o campo value?

Comment: você quer que o valor da url p_t01 preencha o *value* do input pt01? isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem o que quer, pega o valor passado na url **GET** após uma verificação simples adiciona o valor ao *value* do *input*:

```
$p_t01 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pt01'); //pegando o valor
$input = '';
if(!empty($p_t01)){
    echo "<input input id='P101-USERNAME' name='pt01' value='$p_t01' placeholder='Usuário' type='text' />";//adicionando o valor ao input
}
echo $input;
```